# Add and Remove item from observable queue every 1 millisecond

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing, observable

I'm reading data every 1 millisecond from a serial port and want to show the 10 last items of my data in a `DataGrid`.

I used `Queue<T>` and notify the item after `Enqueue` and `Dequeue`, so I created an observable queue class.

```
public class ObservableQueue<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable<T>
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    private readonly Queue<T> _queue;

    public ObservableQueue() => _queue = new Queue<T>();

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        var item = _queue.Dequeue();
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
        return item;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _queue.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

but when I use this class I catch this error:

> Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated

Note: I read my data from the serial port and create a buffer and read my buffer in `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: reading data every 1 millisecond - does it mean what each second DataGrid show and then hides 1000 items?

Comment: How does `Parallel.ForEach` fit in here? Doesn't make sense to me. But anyway. It seems you write faster than you can read. Also, updating every millisecond (given there is data every millisecond) and showing last 10 items will (if it worked) just run through, unreadable to the user. So that, too, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @ASh , I told want to show 10 last items.

Comment: @MahdiAsgari, last 10 items change every 1 ms

Comment: `public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _queue.GetEnumerator();` can be a problem when you continue adding and removing items.

Comment: @kara, what's your Idea. what do I do?

Comment: _"what do I do"_ depends. I'd start with coming up with a reasonable output. As is, and if it worked, an item will run through your Grid in 1/100 of a second. What do you think a user can do with that. He wouldn't even distinguish separate items.

Comment: 1ms from a serialport !!! this is too fast for such old device, 100ms is typical for serial interfaces

Comment: Probably you can omit this entire CollectionChanged-Eventhandling, if you know your collection is changing every 1ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerating your `_queue` can be a problem. You do change your `_queue` while reading it with your `Enumerate()`.

Store your last 10 items in an array at enumerate or clone it:

```cs
public class MyQueue<T>
{
    private Queue<T> _queue = new Queue<T>();
    private T[] last10items = new T[10];
    private int itemsEnqueued = 0;

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(item);
        last10items[itemsEnqueued++%10] = item; // store your last 10 items in an array
        // notify
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        return _queue.Dequeue();
        // notify
    }

    public T[] Last10Items()
    {
        // clone your array if you want to read it. Don't use your queue, because it will change while reading
        return last10items.Clone() as T[]; 
    }
}
```

For a threadsafe-version have a look at:
[ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Example-call to the new queue:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyQueue<int> myQueue = new MyQueue<int>();

    var task1 = Task.Run(()=>
    Parallel.For(0, 10000,
        (x) =>
        {
            myQueue.Enqueue(x);
            Console.WriteLine(x + ": " + string.Join(", ", myQueue.Last10Items()));
        }));

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
        Parallel.For(0, 10000,
            (x) =>
            {
                int y = myQueue.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine(y + ": " + string.Join(", ", myQueue.Last10Items()));
            }));

    task1.Wait();
    task2.Wait();
}
```

Comment: While this circumvents the error, OP is having, I doubt will be of much use. For one, polling the serial port each ms is just - sorry - ridiculous and secondly: just imagine how that would look like (even if the UI could keep up with updates).

Comment: The OPs question was, what his problem causes. He got your comments to think about handling his serial-port. I'm only answering his question. I did add a comment about Concurrent queue and thread-safe `TryDequeue` but this would mean a much longer example and another question ;)

Comment: Absoluteley. I commented before your edit, so nevermind that part about thread-safety. I just wanted to drop my thoughts about the reasonablity (is that a word?) of the question in general.